# Text outside vertex tkz-berge

Tags: tkz-berge

I have just started working with the `tkz-berge` package, I am trying to draw a network flow problem, I have this so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,article]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,%
    petri,%
    topaths}%
\usepackage{tkz-berge}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Network Flow Problem}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75,transform shape]

    \Vertex{3}
    \Vertex[x=0,y=-3]{1}
    \Vertex[x=2,y=-1.5]{2}
    \Vertex[x=4,y=-1]{5}
    \Vertex[x=4,y=-3]{4}
    \Vertex[x=6,y=-1.5]{8}
    \Vertex[x=8,y=0]{6}
    \Vertex[x=8,y=-3]{7}    

    \tikzstyle{EdgeStyle}=[post,dotted]
    \Edge[label=0](1)(3)
    \Edge[label=1](3)(6)
    \Edge[label=1](6)(8)
    \Edge[label=3](2)(1)
    \Edge[label=0](8)(7)

    \tikzstyle{EdgeStyle}=[post]
    \Edge[label=0](3)(2)
    \Edge[label=2](2)(5)
    \Edge[label=2](5)(4)
    \Edge[label=3](8)(5)
    \Edge[label=1](4)(1)
    \Edge[label=4](7)(4)
    \Edge[label=1](7)(6)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And it looks just the way I want it, but I need to get the capacity of each node next to it i.e. `b_{3} = 2 NW of vertex 3`, I have been reading the documentation, but can't find anything on it.

So can it be done, if so how? Thanks in advance

Best Regards 
Steffen

P.S.
If anyone have a better idea for what package to use to draw graphs like this in general, your advice is surely welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `tkz-berge` package has no provisions for two labels per node. But one can use `tikz` commands to add more of them, using e.g. a command

```
\extralabel[optional distance]{angle}{new label}{node name}
```

defined as

```
\newcommand\extralabel[4][0mm]{\node[label={[label distance=#1]#2:#3}] at (#4){};}
```

In your code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,%
    petri,%
    topaths}%
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\extralabel[4][0mm]{\node[label={[label distance=#1]#2:#3}] at (#4){};}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75,transform shape]

    \Vertex{3}            \extralabel  {45}{$b_{3}=2$}{3}
    \Vertex[x=0,y=-3]{1}  \extralabel{-135}{$b_{1}=0$}{1}
    \Vertex[x=2,y=-1.5]{2}\extralabel[1mm]{-90}{$b_{2}=0$}{2}
    \Vertex[x=4,y=-1]{5}
    \Vertex[x=4,y=-3]{4}
    \Vertex[x=6,y=-1.5]{8}
    \Vertex[x=8,y=0]{6}
    \Vertex[x=8,y=-3]{7}    

    \tikzstyle{EdgeStyle}=[post,dotted]
    \Edge[label=0](1)(3)
    \Edge[label=1](3)(6)
    \Edge[label=1](6)(8)
    \Edge[label=3](2)(1)
    \Edge[label=0](8)(7)

    \tikzstyle{EdgeStyle}=[post]
    \Edge[label=0](3)(2)
    \Edge[label=2](2)(5)
    \Edge[label=2](5)(4)
    \Edge[label=3](8)(5)
    \Edge[label=1](4)(1)
    \Edge[label=4](7)(4)
    \Edge[label=1](7)(6)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot, i decided to take a different approach, but this works a charm :-)